# How to testrictpPeople of only specific age to login to our WordPress website

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to know, is there any method through which we can restrict people of only specific age to login to our WordPress website with default login form and social login (Facebook, Google)?
Plugin using: Nextend Social Login

Comment: Is there any method: **YES** (write a plugin  / modify the WP plugin by asking the user to enter the DOB or month/year of the DOB)

Answer (score 1):

Nextend Social Login doesn't provide age gate services. Furthermore, social login doesn't provide you with user birthdays by default (they would have to opt in to share that).

A simple solution would be to add an age gating plugin such as the following: https://wordpress.org/plugins/age-gate/